# Draw the content of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, inkcanvas

I have a textbox on top of an image overlay, which the user can interfere with. Now I want to draw the string onto that image via Graphics, but if I use the direct values of the box for drawing, the text isn't aligned correctly at all. Any tips on how to improve it, or any better way or doing it?

```
if (item is TextBox)
                {
                    var usedItem = item as TextBox;
                    var p1 = new System.Drawing.Point((int)Math.Round(usedItem.Margin.Left), (int)Math.Round(usedItem.Margin.Top));
                    var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", (float)(usedItem.FontSize) );
                    g.DrawString(usedItem.Text, font, new System.Drawing.SolidBrush((System.Drawing.Color)new System.Drawing.ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().
                        ConvertToString(usedItem.Foreground))), p1);
                }
```

How it should look:
[image]

How it ends up looking:
[image: image2]

Comment: "the direct values of the box" - what does this mean? What does "aren't well aligned" mean exactly? Perhaps screenshots could be provided?

Comment: Values like the font size and Margin for coords. I will add an Example

Comment: @Llama Isn't there any better way to draw Inkcanvas.children instead of doing it manually?